# For n rows, subtract one number; then next set of n rows switch to a new number to subtract from

Tags: r

I have a series of readings within one large dataframe as shown below:

```
Plate_ID    Day Well_ID Name    X590_Mean   X590_SD X750_Mean   X750_SD
1   MCBA15 001  0   SPL1    Water   0.196   0.003   0.145   0.004
2   MCBA15 001  0   SPL2    Pyruvic Acid Methyl Ester   0.202   0.001   0.143   0.000
3   MCBA15 001  0   SPL3    Tween 40    0.214   0.036   0.158   0.026
4   MCBA15 001  0   SPL4    Tween 80    0.196   0.000   0.144   0.002
5   MCBA15 001  0   SPL5    ?-Cyclodextrin  0.217   0.012   0.161   0.012
...
33  MCBA15 001  1   SPL1    Water   0.209   0.008   0.111   0.003
34  MCBA15 001  1   SPL2    Pyruvic Acid Methyl Ester   0.371   0.007   0.148   0.003
35  MCBA15 001  1   SPL3    Tween 40    0.481   0.127   0.285   0.088
36  MCBA15 001  1   SPL4    Tween 80    0.242   0.011   0.108   0.002
37  MCBA15 001  1   SPL5    ?-Cyclodextrin  0.277   0.002   0.138   0.001
```

Basically, what I need to do is subtract the mean values (`590 and 750`) that are in the `Water` rows for each `Plate` and `Day` for only the rows that share those same variables (ie. every 32 rows, switch to the next mean values to subtract from the subsequent rows)

The desired output should be:

```
Plate_ID    Day Well_ID Name    X590_Mean   X590_SD X750_Mean   X750_SD
1   MCBA15 001  0   SPL1    Water   0.000   0.003   0.000   0.004
2   MCBA15 001  0   SPL2    Pyruvic Acid Methyl Ester   0.006   0.001   0.000   0.000
3   MCBA15 001  0   SPL3    Tween 40    0.018   0.036   0.013   0.026
...
33  MCBA15 001  1   SPL1    Water   0.000   0.008   0.000   0.003
34  MCBA15 001  1   SPL2    Pyruvic Acid Methyl Ester   0.162   0.007   0.037   0.003
```

Any values that become `negative` should by a `0`.

I have tried the following approach but run into a lot of difficulties.

```
sp2 <- split(dat, with(dat, interaction(Plate_ID, Day)))
sapply(sp2, dim)
d <- function(biolog) {
  x <- biolog$X590_Mean[1]
  biolog$X590_Mean[biolog$X590_Mean > x] <- biolog$X590_Mean - x
  y <- biolog$X750_Mean[1]
  biolog$X750_Mean[biolog$X750_Mean > y] <- biolog$X750_Mean - y
}
lapply(sp2, d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
d <- function(biolog) {
  biolog$X590_Mean <- with(biolog, X590_Mean - X590_Mean[1])
  biolog$X590_Mean <- ifelse(biolog$X590_Mean < 0, 0, biolog$X590_Mean)

  biolog$X750_Mean <- with(biolog, X750_Mean - X750_Mean[1])
  biolog$X750_Mean <- ifelse(biolog$X750_Mean < 0, 0, biolog$X750_Mean)

  biolog
}
```

(I haven't tested it on an actual data set though. Please provide `dput(dat)` if there are any problems with this solution)